# getting complete tree from elastic search in single call

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to store employee hierarchy in elastic search. where CFO, CTO, COO etc report to CEO. And each employee can have their own reportees.

I think above can be done using elastic search parent-child relationship. Can we write a query to get the all reportees(direct reportees and sub-reportees) in a single call.
For example if we query for CEO we should get all employees and for CFO we should get employees in finance dept.

Something similar exists in RDMS like SQL server's CTE.

Answer (score 4):

Parent-child relations in ES is:

1. Parent knows nothing about children
2. Children must provide `_parent` to connect with it and to be routed accodringly.
3. Parent-child mapping is handled by ES via mapping in memory.
4. Parent/child documents is independent in any other aspect.

So, there is no easy way to do it (there's no way to actually store normal form of any relational data as well, because ES in non-relational DB). Workarounds about this:

- query documents with `has_parent`/`has_child` queries (only 1 level of relation works for this)
- store documents as `nested` objects (pay attention, that this model reindexes whole document if any of members changes)
- denormalize data (most natural way for non-relational storages, IMO)

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, avoid thinking about ES in a relational database way. ES isn't so suited for joins/relations, though it can achieve similar effect via the parent/child relations. Don't even think about joins that might involve a undetermined number of depths. CTE can handle without much difficulty but not all relational databases support CTE AFAIK (MySQL being one).

The parent-child relations is more trouble than its worth IMMO. Child docs are routed to shards where their parents reside. In your case of a tree, all documents will eventually trace back to the root document, which will result all your documents to reside in a single shard. The depth of your tree could be quite large (more than 4 or 5 in a not-so-small organization). Also, if you go with this solution, it is quite inconvenient to retrieve (via the `GET` API) a particular child doc from ES based on its ID, because you have to specify its parent IDs all the way up to its root.

I think it's best to store the `PATH` from root up to but not including the current employee as a list of IDs. So each employee has a field like:

```
"superiors": [CEO_ID, CTO_ID, ... , HER_DIRECT_MANAGER_ID],
```

So it is completely denormalized and your application has to prepare for this list.

With this setup, to get all subordinates of an employee:

1. filtering out IDs in this employee's own `superiors` field plus her own ID, either using a filter agg or a filtered query.
2. do a `terms` agg on the `superiors` field and you will have all subordinates of this employee.

I must admit that at least two queries are needed. The first one is a `GET` request to retrieve the `superiors` field of this employee and then the second query to do what I described above.

Also, don't worry about the duplications due to denormalization. ES can handle way more data than you can save here.